# Gulp task dependency

Tags: javascript, gulp

I would like to run (and complete) my "clean" task before running the rest of my build task.

This currently works, although "run" is deprecated and I'd like to replace it:

```
gulp.task('build', ['clean'],function() {
    gulp.run(['styles-nomaps','usemin','scripts','assets']);
});
```

What's the proper syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [run-sequence plugin.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence)

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out. Isn't there also to do it some way with dependencies?

Comment: Have you seen this https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-tasks-in-series.md

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rimraf](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf) util to clean files, it can be run in sync mode:

clean.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rimraf = require('rimraf');

gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
  rimraf.sync(paths.assets, cb); // Make sure you pass callback
});
```